# NameError: X while executing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) script

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

I am trying to execute a wlst script as below,but have no idea why i get that error.

```
DEV3_INTF_Domain$ ./stopDomain.sh "DEV3_INTF_Domain"

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/home/applmgr/duquesnewlst/lib/stopDomain_wlst.py", line 13, in ?
NameError: X
```

Script code:

```
import duquesnewlst
from stopNodeManager_wlst import stopNM
from stopServer_wlst import stopMS

domCfg = duquesnewlst.domainConfig()

# Preload security modules
domCfg.adminUser()

domCfg.bootOrder.reverse()
for (None,msName) in domCfg.bootOrder:
        if X in domCfg.serversOnHost:
                stopMS(msName, domCfg)

stopNM(domCfg)
```

Comment: if X in ... should be replaced by if msName in ...    no ?

Comment: actually you are right.it should be so.glad you noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

if X in ... should be replaced by if msName in ...